# Terminal Help - Reverting a Standard Mac user account back to an admin account?

Tags: macos, command-line, user-account, administrator

I've been doing a Jamf now roll out, but have mucked up the user account by using this terminal command:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -d UserName -t user admin
```

Which basically made the admin account switch to a standard user account.

I now need to revert back the standard user account to admin, but am struggling to find the terminal command that works to revert back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same command.

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a insertusernamehere -t user admin
```

Comment: How can a standard user run `sudo`?

Comment: You need to boot to single-user mode to do this if there's no user with `sudo` access.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other admin account, the steps to create a new one include:

- Pushing a new admin user via jamf
- Potentially booting to recovery based on what exact version of macOS and what hardware is running
- Making a backup (or validating the backup is complete) and erase/install/restore from backup.
- Using another Mac and [target disk mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/target-disk-mode) or [share disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/share-disk) mode to migrate the data onto a new Mac.

There is no undo for group changes and you’ll need another admin user to reverse the change on this OS [with sudo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/463231/5472).

Answer (score 0):

I would also look at [Privileges for macOS](https://github.com/SAP/macOS-enterprise-privileges).

It is designed to allow users to work as a standard user for day-to-day use, and provides a quick and easy way to get administrator rights when needed.